# Networkx ignore nodes with certain values for attributes in shortest path

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to calculate the shortest path in a graph from A and D, but only considering nodes with a given attribute. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

cols = ['node_a','node_b','travel_time','attribute']

data = [['A','B',3,'attribute1'],
        ['B','C',1,'attribute1'],
        [ 'C','D',7,'attribute1'],
         ['D','E',3,'attribute1'],
         ['E','F',2,'attribute1'],
         ['F','G',4,'attribute1'],
         ['A','L',4,'attribute2'],
         ['L','D',3,'attribute2']
         ]
edges = pd.DataFrame(data)
edges.columns = cols
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edges,'node_a','node_b', ['travel_time','attribute'])
```

If i  want to calculate the shortest path from A to D, the default method would be

```
nx.shortest_path(G,'A','D',weight='travel_time')
```

Which could give me `['A', 'L', 'D']` but if i only want to consider nodes with `attribute1`, this wouldnt be the case. I cant see how to modify it though, is there a canonical way how instead of coding my own shortest path?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you just want edges with `attribute1`,  rather than nodes with `attribute1`.  Is that right?

Comment: [I want to warn you of a bug in the accepted answer - see my comment there]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an out of the box solution, but you could make a subgraph from all nodes with the desired property (quick and dirty implementation):

```
edges = [(a,b) for (a,b,e) in G.edges(data=True) if e['attribute']=='attribute1']
nodes = []
for a,b in edges:
    nodes += [a,b]

nx.shortest_path(G.subgraph(nodes),'A','D',weight='travel_time')
```

**Edit:** @Joel rightly pointed out, this answer can give wrong results. 
To avoid those, you can query a duplicate of the graph that only has edges with the correct attributes:

```
H = G.copy()
edges_to_remove = [e for e in H.edges(data=True) if not e['attribute']=='attribute1']
H.remove_edges_from(edges_to_remove)
nx.shortest_path(H,'A','D',weight='travel_time')
```

**Edit2**: Following up on this idea, I think one can make it a bit faster by removing and re-adding the edges from the original graph, without copying:

```
edges_to_remove = [e for e in G.edges(data=True) if not e['attribute']=='attribute1']
G.remove_edges_from(edges_to_remove)
nx.shortest_path(G,'A','D',weight='travel_time')
G.add_edges_from(edges_to_remove)
```

Comment: There's a potential bug here.   If `u` has an edge with the right attribute to `v` and similarly `v` has an edge with the right attribute to `w`, but there is a `u` to `w` edge with the wrong attribute, the subgraph you've got will have the `u` to `w` edge.  To see this, add an `F` to `L` edge with `attribute1` to the network the OP posted.

Comment: Further fix: that generates a `tuple does not support indexing` as the edges are a tuple of three. using `edges_to_remove = [e for e in G.edges(data=True) if not e[2]['attribute']=='attribute1']` worked

Comment: Just discovered a serious problem with that approach in warped's answer, this is an undirected graph and some nodes have multiple edges, this seems to disconnect the graph for some reason? @Joel

Comment: Hm, the fixes should work with multiple edges (directed or undirected), as only the edges that do not have the property are removed. Can you post an edge with actual data, and/or a graph for which this approach fails?